# What does undo undo?

Tags: undo-redo

The undo command feels a bit random. Sometimes it undoes massive chunks, sometimes tiny changes. How is the cut-off point determined?

Comment: This great [series of videos](http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/novice/) can help getting started with vim

Comment: @mattb cf. http://vimcasts.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It undo the last command (e.g. `i`, `c`, `d`).

The insert (`i`) command can indeed be either:

- rather large if you type a long text without leaving the insert mode or
- rather short if you just make a small change and leave the insert mode or use the right or left arrow to move the cursor.

In insert mode you you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> to split the insert operation and create shorter undo chunk.

On the opposite you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> right before the right <kbd>-></kbd> or left <kbd><-</kbd> arrow to avoid to split the insert operation and make a longer undo chunk.

Somes add the following mapping in their `.vimrc` file to make sure every words inserted in insert mode are in their own undo chunk.

```
:inoremap <space> <C-g>u<space>
```

But the recommended Vim way is to leave insert mode after each "meaningful" operation.

Comment: I'm not personally a fan of the `<space>` thing; really, the idea is to leave insert mode when you pause (_i.e._, make hitting `<esc>` a habit). cf. `:help undo-blocks`, `:help :changes`, `:help change.txt`